# Remaining time beetwen two time

Tags: php, mysql, time

i have `time data` in database, i'm recording time with `time()` function (value 1551866538) on database, and i want write php remaining time for 1 day but as 24 hour. I try `date_diff()` function but i get error every time, thanks for help.

```
$mysqltime = $data->registerdate; // 1551866538
$now = time();

$remainingtime = $now - $mysqltime; // I want show as hour
```

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i added my code.

Comment: Are you just trying to format seconds in hours:minutes ?

Comment: If the difference will be more than 24 hours then you want to show days?

Comment: i want to show like this, "Remeaning time 4 Hour 21 Min." When finished remaining time "Time Expired"

Comment: Have you looked at [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff) already? Maybe you could use it some way.

Comment: have a million script about this subject on internet. i cant use that script for a few line php code.

Comment: @Koray check my another short answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use The `DateTime` class as below:

```
$today      = new DateTime('now');
$tomorrow   = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', '1551866538'));
$difference = $today->diff($tomorrow);

echo $difference->format('%h hours %i minutes remaining');
```

Output

```
1 hours 42 minutes remaining
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, best answer, i run this code and exactly like i want.

Comment: I've realized now, its estimated time, please explain how to show remaining time 24 hours to back.

Comment: Ok i solve this problem. I replaced this code like this..  $tomorrow   = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', '1551866538' + 60 * 60 * 24));

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqltime = $data->registerdate; // 1551866538
$now = time();

$remainingtime = $now - $mysqltime;
echo $hours = round($remainingtime / (60 * 60)); // hours
```

Comment: This will not show minutes. It will round to the nearest hour.

Comment: i cant understand $datediff variable.

Comment: wrong code echo $hours = round($remainingtime / (60 * 60));

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

// Declare and define two dates 
$date1 = strtotime("2016-06-01 22:45:00");  
$date2 = strtotime("2018-09-21 10:44:01");  

// Formulate the Difference between two dates 
$diff = abs($date2 - $date1);  


// To get the year divide the resultant date into 
// total seconds in a year (365*60*60*24) 
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));  


// To get the month, subtract it with years and 
// divide the resultant date into 
// total seconds in a month (30*60*60*24) 
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) 
                               / (30*60*60*24));  


// To get the day, subtract it with years and  
// months and divide the resultant date into 
// total seconds in a days (60*60*24) 
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 -  
             $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24)); 


// To get the hour, subtract it with years,  
// months & seconds and divide the resultant 
// date into total seconds in a hours (60*60) 
$hours = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24  
       - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24) 
                                   / (60*60));  


// To get the minutes, subtract it with years, 
// months, seconds and hours and divide the  
// resultant date into total seconds i.e. 60 
$minutes = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24  
         - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24  
                          - $hours*60*60)/ 60);  


// To get the minutes, subtract it with years, 
// months, seconds, hours and minutes  
$seconds = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24  
         - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 
                - $hours*60*60 - $minutes*60));  

// Print the result 
printf("%d years, %d months, %d days, %d hours, "
     . "%d minutes, %d seconds", $years, $months, 
             $days, $hours, $minutes, $seconds);  
?>
```

Output:

```
2 years, 3 months, 21 days, 11 hours, 59 minutes, 1 seconds
```

[Reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-php/)

Comment: The idea is more or less correct, but if the difference is very small it will show 0 years, 0 months....

Comment: You can place if condition to check 0 years/months.

Comment: i have not formatted time, my data is 1551866538 in database, i know i must convert this data but i didnt, and your code very long, it must be very short way this.